# How to write a BST to a text file

Tags: java, file-io, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a binary Search tree to a text file in sorted order, my write method is in my BST class. When I print out the BST in Order Tranversal it works perfectly. When I try to write it to a text file it works but the current node being written inserts null to the text file instead of the node

```
public void write(Node focusNode)
{
    
    try{
        // Creates a FileWriter
        FileWriter fileName = new FileWriter("Binary Search Tree.txt");

        // Creates a BufferedWriter
        BufferedWriter  bw = new BufferedWriter(fileName);
        if (focusNode != null) {
            bw.write(focusNode.leftChild+"\n"); //adds the  left node

            bw.write(focusNode+"\n");//add the current node

            bw.write(focusNode.rightChild+"\n"); // add the right node
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Your binary search tree is empty");
        }
        bw.close();
    }   
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.print("An error occured try again ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is the `null` prints, this happens because you're printing the left and right children without checking if they exist first.

Two ways to correct it: either to add a nullity check before the print, or count on the recursive call to do it for you.

**Another problem:**

You keep opening the file and overriding it's content!
You should open it only once, and then call a recursive function and pass into it `bw` so that all the calls will write into the same file without overriding the content that the other calls wrote

The code should look something like this (not tested!):

```
public void writeTree(Node root) {
    try {
        FileWriter fileName = new FileWriter("Binary Search Tree.txt"); 
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileName);
        write(root, bw);  
        bw.close();  
    }   
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.print("An error occured try again ");
    }    
}

public void write(Node focusNode, BufferedWriter bw) {   
    if (focusNode == null) { 
        return;
    }
    write(focusNode.leftChild, bw); // calls recursively
    bw.write(focusNode+"\n");
    write(focusNode.rightChild, bw); // calls recursively
}
```

Comment: it works, to read the file do I have to use recursion or just the normal reader

Comment: @CasperJosiah to read the file no recursion is needed, you can simply read and print it and it will print the BST "in order" just like you wrote it

Comment: @CasperJosiah your last comment is not clear

Comment: since I stored the bst to a text file, I wanted to know whether I had to use recursion or just the usual way of reading a text file to convert the text file to a tree

Comment: @CasperJosiah no recursion is needed when reading the text file

Comment: @ Nir Alfasi, ok.  I don't know why I can't ask questions for a week. I'm gonna edit my question, to show you how I went about it could you take a look

Comment: @CasperJosiah please don't: if you have a new question about constructing a BST from a file as an input, please publish it as a separate question because it's a different question. If you'll modify this one it will mess up the context of the original question/answer.